# Can I use a "would + was" structure in a conditional that refers to a real situation in the past?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I am trying to describe a protocol in the Methods section of my paper (protocol: refer the patient to hospital X if the test is positive). It is something that happened in the past and I consider it a real situation in the past. So, should I say:

> A) The patients *would be referred* to hospital X if the test *was* positive;
>
> B) The patients *would be referred* to hospital X if the test *were* positive;

or

> The patients *were referred* to hospital X if the test *was* positive.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "were" is an exception that applies only to unreal conditionals—that is, situations that do not reflect reality. (Hint: unreal conditionals often contain words like “would” or “ought to.”) When you’re talking about a possibility that did happen or might be true, use “was” and “were” as you normally would. For example;

> If I were [not ***was***] a rich man, I **would** make more charitable
>   donations.
>
> If he were [not ***was***] here right now, he **would** help us.

However;

> If I was [not ***were***] rude to you, I apologize.

But;

> If I were [not ***was***] rude to you, I **would** apologize.

For more: [“Was” or “Were” in the “If” Clause/Conditional](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/)